# How often should I change my Nissan Sentra's (2012 model) oil?

Tags: oil-change

I have a 2012 nissan sentra.

Here is the manual. I looked into it but it doesn't seem to indicate the frequency of which I should change the oil. It does mention that the oil change light indicator should not be the indicator for changing oil. It does mention stop and go.

From what I hear, I should change my oil every 5,000 to 15,000 miles. My mechanic gives me the 3,000 mile sticker but I have read that this is not true.

My usage of my car:

I drive an hour away and back a week.
Twice a week, I drive 20-30 minutes away and back.
Daily, I drive about 10-20 minutes and back (going to the gym, grocery store, etc).

Comment: Do you use synthetic or conventional oil?

Comment: I do not know. I have a mechanic who does it for me. I will have to make sure to ask him next time. I am right now around 4,000 miles in. I am reading around and it says that for this vehicle, synthetic oil is optional.

Comment: I'd consider sending your oil in to get analyzed by a place like Blackstone Labs when you do an oil change. They'll take a look at the metals that are in the oil as well as the quality of the oil and be able to make the best recommendation on change interval. The advantage of doing this is you get a personalized recommendation based on the health and state of your engine as well as the oil and filter you use. http://www.blackstone-labs.com/

Comment: So just put it in a container? Is that expensive?

Comment: They'll send you the collection kit for free. You basically fill a small container with a few ounces of the old oil as it's being drained, package it up, and mail it. The analysis is $28 plus a few bucks for shipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the recommendations from Nissan, your oil change interval for "less severe" conditions is 7500mi or 6 months.  That comes from this [2012 Service and Maintenance Guide](https://owners.nissanusa.com/content/techpub/common/2012/2012-nissan-service-maintenance-guide.pdf) that lists all other recommended service as well.

Note that these "official" guidelines assume that you use the same brand and type of oil that Nissan uses, so this can vary if you use a cheaper or better quality oil.